# When result.rows is [], how do I test for that?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

So I have a question about when result is []. I am using express, nodejs and postgresql to create an REST QPI. Now, the question that I have is. When result.rows is [], does that mean that is null? I tried doing "if(result == null)", but that didn't seem to work either. Thanks for the help!

```
client.query("select waiter_id from students", function(err, result){
    if(err){
        res.json({success: false, msg: "error"});
    }
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.rows);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an empty array, so you have to check the `length` property

```
if (result.length === 0)
```

or

```
if (!result.length)
```

sometimes it can be useful to check that an array was returned first to avoid errors

```
if (Array.isArray(result ) && result.length) {
     // It's an array, and it has content
} else {
     // It's either not an array at all, or it's empty
}
```

Comment: Wow... that was stupid of me haha. I did if(result.rows.length === 0). THANKS @adeneo